# angular2 npm start reload so slow

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular

I've been wondering why my npm start loads so slow even though I've only changed file file, it takes about a minute to read the change and takes another minute to load  the page. It's making the development really slow because of the issue, I have to restart and run the application again just to gain few seconds faster.

The app folder is only 167kb in total, but my node_modules is big, not sure if these dependencies are all for angular but it seems like the whole npm library has been installed in my node_modules folder.

Edit: ***Looks like its maxing out my CPU while its reloading the files which is strange.***

[image]

while my package.json dev dependencies are very little and the rest are the angular dependencies from angular installation.

```
"devDependencies": {
"body-parser": "^1.15.2",
"concurrently": "^2.0.0",
"cors": "^2.7.1",
"express": "^4.14.0",
"file-system": "^2.2.1",
"gulp": "^3.9.1",
"gulp-clean-css": "^2.0.12",
"gulp-less": "^3.1.0",
"gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
"gulp-useref": "^3.1.0",
"gulp-watch": "^4.3.8",
"jquery": "^3.1.0",
"lite-server": "^2.2.0",
"merge-stream": "^1.0.0",
"momentjs": "^1.1.12",
"ng2-bootstrap": "^1.0.24",
"typescript": "^1.8.10",
"typings": "^1.0.4"
}
```

Comment: are you using the latest version of nodejs?

Comment: Yeah I'm using the 6.3.1 or should I uninstall that and install the 4.4.7?

Comment: no, just querying if you have the latest version or not.

Comment: Oh right, but yeah this problem is really frustrating and slowing down my development. Has anyone else had this issue or you @th1rdey3?

Comment: Why you have express and lite-server at the same time? Does your project contain both the server and browser code?

Comment: I have whatever the angular2 installation has, I've followed their instruction.

Comment: Is is okay to use npm install --legacy-bundling? to nest all dependencies rather than installing them in their own folder? I think that's what causing for the application to slow when reloading the files.

Comment: I also have this exact issue. node_modules dir has 362 directories. looking into it right now

Comment: I think those are the dependencies required for other dependencies for angular2, I used gulp legacy install to bundle up everything rather having this individual folders for each dependencies. But pls add your answer if you found a solution.

Comment: I just updated from the last beta to the most recent release according to the quickstart guide and I am having a ton of issues with compilation.  Getting Javascript heap out of memory errors, incremental repairs are taking upwards of 4 minutes if they even execute.  What the hell is going on?